# Differentiate $e^x\sqrt x$ using the definition

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, limits

Can you help me differentiate this function, I can't get it right:

$$f(x) = e^x\sqrt x$$

at $x_0>0$, using the definition :

$$f'(x_0)=\lim_{h\to 0}{f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)\over h} =  \lim_{h\to 0}{e^{x_0+h}\sqrt {x_0+h}-e^{x_0} \sqrt x_0\over h}$$

Comment: Differentiate..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not enjoyable, but you can do it this way:
$$\begin{align}
{f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)\over h}
&= \frac{e^{x_0+h}\sqrt{x_0+h}-e^{x_0}\sqrt{x_0}}{h}
= e^{x_0}\sqrt{x_0}\frac{e^{h}\sqrt{1+\frac{h}{x_0}}-1}{h}
\\&= \frac{e^{x_0}\sqrt{x_0}}{e^{h}\sqrt{1+\frac{h}{x_0}}+1}\frac{e^{2h}(1+\frac{h}{x_0})-1}{h}
= \frac{e^{x_0}\sqrt{x_0}}{e^{h}\sqrt{1+\frac{h}{x_0}}+1}\frac{e^{2h}-1+e^{2h}\frac{h}{x_0}}{h}
\end{align}$$
When $h\to 0$, the first factor clearly converges to $\frac{e^{x_0}\sqrt{x_0}}{e^{0}\sqrt{1+0}+1} = \frac{e^{x_0}\sqrt{x_0}}{2}$ by continuity. As for the second, we have 
$$
\frac{e^{2h}-1+e^{2h}\frac{h}{x_0}}{h}
= \frac{e^{2h}-1}{h}+e^{2h}\frac{1}{x_0}
= 2\frac{e^{2h}-1}{2h}+e^{2h}\frac{1}{x_0}
$$
which converges to $2\exp'(0)+e^0\frac{1}{x_0} = 2+\frac{1}{x_0}$ when $h\to 0$. Putting it all together, you get

> $$\begin{align}
> {f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)\over h}
> &\xrightarrow[h\to0]{} \frac{e^{x_0}\sqrt{x_0}}{2}\left(2+\frac{1}{x_0}\right)=e^{x_0}\sqrt{x_0}+\frac{e^{x_0}}{2\sqrt{x_0}}
> \end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align}
{e^{x_0+h}\sqrt{x_0+h}-e^{x_0}\sqrt{x_0}\over h}
&=e^{x_0}\left(e^h\sqrt{x_0+h}-\sqrt{x_0+h}+\sqrt{x_0+h}-\sqrt{x_0}\over h \right)\\
&=e^{x_0}\sqrt{x_0+h}\left(e^h-1\over h \right)+e^{x_0}\left({\sqrt{x_0+h}-\sqrt{x_0}\over h} \cdot{\sqrt{x_0+h}+\sqrt{x_0}\over \sqrt{x_0+h}+\sqrt{x_0}} \right)\\
&=e^{x_0}\sqrt{x_0+h}\left(e^h-1\over h \right)+e^{x_0}\left({1\over \sqrt{x_0+h}+\sqrt{x_0}} \right)\\
\end{align}$$

Assuming you know $\lim_{h\to0}{e^h-1\over h}=1$, then

$$\lim_{h\to0}{e^{x_0+h}\sqrt{x_0+h}-e^{x_0}\sqrt{x_0}\over h}=e^{x_0}\sqrt{x_0}+e^{x_0}\left(1\over2\sqrt{x_0}\right)$$

so

$$(e^x\sqrt x)'=e^x\sqrt x+{e^x\over2\sqrt x}$$

Remark:  The main trick here is really just the standard derivation of the product rule:

$$\begin{align}
{f(x+h)g(x+h)-f(x)g(x)\over h}
&={f(x+h)g(x+h)-f(x+h)g(x)+f(x+h)g(x)-f(x)g(x)\over h}\\
&=f(x+h)\left(g(x+h)-g(x)\over h\right)+\left(f(x+h)-f(x)\over h\right)g(x)\\
&\to f(x)g'(x)+f'(x)g(x)\quad\text{as } h\to0
\end{align}$$